# React Native - TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing 'ImageLoader' issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, imageloader

Cannot startup ios app after upgrade RN version from 0.59.9 to 0.62.2. Have no idea where the issue is and how to fix it. Help please!

[image]

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: @alimcharaniya unfortunately not, rolled back to RN 0.61.5

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution for 0.61.5. It works on 0.63.2 tho.